# Sum of Alternating Factorial Products

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Simplify $\sum^{n}_{k=1} (-1)^k(n-k)!(n+k)!$.

I thought of interpreting a term $(n-k)!(n+k)!=\frac{(2n)!}{\dbinom{2n}{n-k}}$,  but I do not know of any ways to sum this efficiently.

Comment: How can the estate it identity be true? The left hand side is a natural number where are the right hand side is necessarily a rational number.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern:  think he forgot $(2n)!$ on the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

By using Euler's Beta function:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k \Gamma(n+k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1) = \Gamma(2n+2)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}(-1)^k z^{n+k}(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz $$
equals:
$$ (2n+1)! \int_{0}^{1} z^{n+1}\left[(-z)^n-(1-z)^n\right]\,dz =(2n+1)!\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+2}-B(n+1,n+2)\right]$$
or:
$$ \color{red}{(-1)^n\frac{(2n+1)!}{2n+2}-\frac{n!(n+1)!}{2n+2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^k(n-k)!(n+k)!=(-1)^k(n-k)!(n+k)!\frac{n+k+1+(n-k+1)}{2n+2}$
$=\frac{1}{2n+2}\Delta\Big[-(-1)^{k+1}\big(n+1-(k+1)\big)!(n+k+1)!\Big]$
$$\;$$
Therefore
$$\;$$
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k(n-k)!(n+k)!=\frac{1}{2n+2}\bigg((-1)^n(2n+1)!-n!(n+1)!\bigg)$