# Simplifying an alternating sum of a product of factorials

Tags: number-theory, summation, factorial, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

For integers $a$ and $b$, I am curious how to simplify an expression of the form
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k (a+k)! (b+k)!$$

I assume there is some simplification using properties of gamma and beta functions, as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2210332/687835), but I am not well-versed enough in that type of number theory.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer.*

Factorials are growing so fast that, more than likely, the sum can be *approximated* by its last term, that is to say
$$S_{a,b,n}=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k (a+k)!\, (b+k)! \sim (-1)^n (a+n)!\, (b+n)!=T_{a,b,n}$$

Trying for $a=3$, $b=5$, a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & T_{a,b,n} & S_{a,b,n} \\
 1 & -17280 & -17280 \\
 2 & 604800 & 587520 \\
 3 & -29030400 & -28442880 \\
 4 & 1828915200 & 1800472320 \\
 5 & -146313216000 & -144512743680 \\
 6 & 14485008384000 & 14340495640320 \\
 7 & -1738201006080000 & -1723860510439680 \\
 8 & 248562743869440000 & 246838883359000320 \\
 9 & -41758540970065920000 & -41511702086706919680 \\
 10 & 8142915489162854400000 & 8101403787076147480320 \\
 11 & -1824013069572479385600000 & -1815911665785403238119680 \\
 12 & 465123332740982243328000000 & 463307421075196840089880320 
\end{array}
\right)$$